# Mover side bar a la izquierda

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

soy nuevo en estos temas. Quiero mover un side bar a la izquierda https://eurocimbras.com/desarrollo/categoria-producto/sin-categorizar/

En inspeccionar elemento, me aparece que la clase corresponde a esto:

```
div class="col col-sm-3 col-xs-12 sidebar right widgets_holder" style="min-height: 554px;"
```

He investigado en diferentes fuentes y he intentado hacer esto en mis archivos app.min.css y bootstrap.css:

```
.col col-sm-3 col-xs-12 sidebar right widgets_holder { float:right; }
```

Pero sin resultados satisfactorios.

Intente esto tambien:

```
.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 { float: right; }
```

Me da lo que quiero, pero me mueve toda la pagina de su lugar. y yo lo que quiero es mover solamente el sidebar a la izquierda

Alguna idea?, gracias :D

Comment: Por favor comparte tu código para poder ver cómo lo tienes implementado y que así algún compañero pueda darte una respuesta acertada para tus necesidades. Si puedo decirte que tienes la clase 'right' que como su nombre indica ves colocar los elementos a la derecha... empieza por quitarla si quieres que se coloque a la izquierda.

Answer (score 0):

Para colocar tu 'sidebar' a la izquierda basta con que inviertas el orden de colocación de las columnas que les has dado en este momento. Tu 'sidebar' tiene una clase 'right' que lo coloca a la derecha mientras en las columnas con imagen y texto tienen una clase 'left'. Si a cada uno de estos elementos les inviertes la clase se colocan como comentabas. Luego tendrás que ajustar con 'css' o con el 'cms' la colocación interior de elementos:

```
  <div class="col col-sm-9 col-xs-12 content right" style="min-height: 524px;">
```

y

```
 <div class="col col-sm-3 col-xs-12 sidebar left widgets_holder" style="min-height: 524px;">
```